# Spring MVC not authenticating versus database

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-security

We are working with Spring MVC 4.0, but we are unable to autheticate users against database. We have the following Java security configuration class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

/**
 * Configura el acceso a la aplicación para los usuarios.
 */
@Autowired
protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    String queryUsers = "SELECT acod_usuario as username, ades_clave as password, true as enabled " +
                        "FROM t_usuarios " +
                        "WHERE acod_usuario = ?";
    String queryAuth = "SELECT acod_usuario as username, 'ROLE_USER' as role" +
                       "FROM t_usuarios " +
                       "WHERE acod_usuario = ?";
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).
        usersByUsernameQuery(queryUsers).
        authoritiesByUsernameQuery(queryAuth);
}

/**
 * Configuración de la seguridad HTTP.
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers("/home","/403","/resources/**").permitAll().
            anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ROLE_USER, ANONYMOUS").
            and().
         formLogin().
            loginPage("/home").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").
            and().
         logout().
            permitAll().
            and().
         exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403").and().
            csrf();
}
}
```

Pagres authorization is working fine, but we are unable to make login works with a valid user. All users can entry the application, instead they do not exist in database. Data source configuration is working fine too,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.justinfact.web.*")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
private UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO;
private CatalogosDAO catalogosDAO;
private CFEDAO cfeDAO;

/**
 * Registra la base de datos de backend, creando un connection pool.
 * 
 * @return DataSource
 */
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db");
    basicDataSource.setUsername("xxxxx");
    basicDataSource.setPassword("xxxxx");
    basicDataSource.setInitialSize(5);
    basicDataSource.setMaxActive(10);
    basicDataSource.setAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed(true);
    return basicDataSource;
}

/**
 * Se registra el template para trabajar con JDBC
 * 
 * @return JdbcTemplate
 */
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

but it seems that no query is executing. We have tested the querys and works fine for us. Login page is an standard one:

```
<div class="contenedor">
    <img src="<s:url value='resources' />/images/logo.jpg"     width="220" height="90" border="0" />
<h1>
    Acceso Sistema  
</h1>

<br>
<c:url value="login" var="loginURL"/>
<sf:form id="homeForm" action="${loginURL}" method="POST" commandName="user">
    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
        <p>Usuario o clave incorrecta</p>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
        <p>Ha salido correctamente de la aplicación</p>
    </c:if>
    <div class="div_form">
        <sf:input path="rut" placeholder="RUT empresa"/>
    </div>
    <div class="div_form">
        <sf:input path="username" placeholder="nombre de usuario"/><sf:errors path="username"  />
    </div>
    <div class="div_form">
        <sf:password path="password" placeholder="contraseña"/>
    </div>
    <div><a id="ingresar" href="#">Acceder</a></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</sf:form>
```

And we have a basic controller file to manage this operations:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);


/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    /*
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
    */
    model.addAttribute("user",new Login());
    return "home";
}

/**
 * Realiza la gestión de la operación de login/acceso al sistema con usuario y clave.
 * 
 * @param user
 * @param model
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@Valid Login user, Model model, Errors errors) {
    logger.info("en Login");
    logger.info(errors.toString());
    logger.info(user.toString());
    System.out.println(user);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "login";
}
}
```

What we are doing the wrong way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Comment: btw, are you sure you want 'anonymus' for anyRequest() - 
anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ROLE_USER, ANONYMOUS").

Comment: I don't get exceptions, just go to the next page, instead the user is not valid. I don't know where to use the "/login" action in Spring Security, how to invoke it

Comment: If I comment the "login" action method on controller, an exception raises: no way to manage /login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

One problem was I have a "/login" action with POST in my controllers, that overwrites the default login action from Spring security. Now it's working with some other changes.

Thanks